# Displaying multiple array items and returning to the start once the end is reached

Tags: c#

I have a main array with a number of items, e.g. 100 (itemsArray)
I have second array of 7 items that is filled from the main array depending on what is selected (selectedItemsArray)

the second array is output to the screen, when i press left or right the next item or previous item in the array is displayed, however the 3 previous are displayed before and the next 3 are displayed after.

however once the end of the array is reached (or the item goes below 0) it crashes (not a surprise) but how can i calculate what number in the array should be selected once the end or start of 0 is reached

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace test2
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            string[] itemsArray = new string[100];
            int selectedIndex = 0;

            private void displayItems(string[] items)
            {
                StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("");
                for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++)
                {
                    output.AppendLine(items[i]);
                }
                textBox1.Text = output.ToString();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.Count(); i++)
                {
                    itemsArray[i] = "Item " + i;
                }
                callItems();
            }

            private void callItems()
            {
                string[] selectedItemsArray = new string[7];
                Array.Copy(itemsArray, selectedIndex, selectedItemsArray, 0, 7);
                displayItems(selectedItemsArray);
            }

            private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
            {
                switch (e.KeyData)
                {
                    case Keys.Left:
                        {
                            selectedIndex--;
                            callItems();
                            break;
                        }
                    case Keys.Right:
                        {
                            selectedIndex++;
                            callItems();
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

i hope that makes sense and appreciate any help anyone can give me

Comment: 1) Don't use `itemsArray.Count()`. There's a perfectly fine `itemsArray.Length` property that gives you what you want. 2) You can use the `%` operator - `selectedIndex = (selectedIndex + 1) % itemsArray.Length`. 3) Think well about what you're doing. This seems like bad design at a glance.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, im a hobby programmer so im afraid alot of the finer points i might have missed but thanks for the advice and I will definitely take it onboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you'd change this:

```
Array.Copy(itemsArray, selectedIndex, selectedItemsArray, 0, 7);
displayItems(selectedItemsArray);
```

to

```
for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
{
    selectedItemsArray[i] = itemsArray[(i+selectedIndex)%itemsArray.Length];
}
```

Also, you may want to make sure your selectedIndex won't ge below 0 in your `KeyDown` handlers

```
case Keys.Left:
{
    if(selectedIndex!=0)
    {
        selectedIndex--;
    }
    else
    {
        selectedIndex = itemsArray.Length-1;
    }
    callItems();
    break;
}
```

same for going right side

```
case Keys.Right:
{
    if(selectedIndex != itemsArray.Length-1)
    {
        ++selectedIndex;
    }
    else
    {
        selectedIndex = 0;
    }
    callItems();
    break;
}
```

And on top of that I'd make sure non of those will be fired, if there are no items in the `itemsArray` at all, because it won't work then.

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply, the code you have given me works perfectly scrolling from left to right but going the other way it still crashes when i reach 0, do i need a second part for going the other way?

Comment: @user3810392 I've made a proper edit if that's what you were after. Please check the code and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly, im still not 100% sure what the first piece of code is doing with the % but im going to go through it now and get my head around it.  The left and right parts i get and had started writing when your edits came in.
Really appreciate the help

Comment: @user3810392 The `%` sign is the remainder operator. F.e. dividing two integer numbers, let's say 5 and 2, leaves a quotient of 2 (`/` operator in C#) and a remainder of 1. So if your array would have a length of 50 and your selection index would be 50 aswell, dividing them would leave you a remainder of 0, hence `itemsArray[50%50]` is equal to `itemsArray[0]`. For index equal to 115, `115%50` would give you 15, since 115/50 is 2, and the rest is 15/50.
Also, if you find my answer helpfull, I'd appreciate marking it as the correct one. Regards.

Comment: thank you again, I now understand what its doing and its doing exactly what i was trying to do by calculating the remainder etc. myself when i tried it a few days ago, comforting to know i was on the right track